# Angular2 Injector - Dynamically choose Service Implementation

Tags: angular, angular-services

For better testing and separating frontend / backend development we are currently trying to find a dynamic way to provide mock service implementations in devMode.

The idea is to specify in your environment which services shall be mocked and have the injector then return either the real or the mocked implementation based on this.

The question is now if it is possible to dynamically do this for every service the injector provides or if we have to use a separate factory (doing the same thing) for every service?

```
// pseudo code
onRequestProviderFor(serviceName)
{
  if(environment.mockTheseServices.contains(serviceName))
  {
    return new "Mock"+serviceName.ts
  }
  else
  {
    return new serviceName.ts
  }
}
```

Is this possible? And is there a hook in the injector process we could use to do this (in devMode)?

Comment: I think you need a separate factory for every service. You can do some code generation, that updates barrel files so that the same imports lead to different classes.

Comment: You can add custom providers when you bootstrap the app, have you tried that?

Comment: do you intend to have that code `environment.mockTheseServices.contains(serviceName)` in production?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I was afraid so, but thanks for confirming.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was looking for the cleanest way to do this dynamically for all services, not just for one (unless I misunderstood you).

Comment: @Maximus no, as mentioned, devMode only ;-)

Comment: @TommyF, can you add more details and code to the question details? It's not clear how you can use a service in dev mode only

Comment: @Maximus I think you misunderstood, the question was what the simplest / cleanest way is to dynamically provide mock implementations of certain services during development (for example if the backend isn't fully developed yet or we need to test some special cases) and if there is a way to not have to use a separate factory for every service but instead do it dynamically for every service by something similar to the pseudo code above. But it seems this is not possible right now...

Comment: If you're talking about replacing *the API your services are calling*, see e.g. https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api. If you want to override the services themselves, try bootstrapping with `[{ provide: Service, useClass: MockService }. ...]` in dev mode. Beyond that, please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider creating a separate mock server using something like https://github.com/typicode/json-server ?

I think it would keep your project code cleaner to not include mock services in the same code base.